# div with cdkDrag on top of mat-slider doesn't hide the slider button

Tags: css, typescript, angular-cdk-drag-drop, angular14

I'm writing an angular14 application.

I have a `div` element that has `cdkDrag` for it to be moveable, and behind it i have a few buttons and sliders and i noticed that the slider button is still visible when i drag that div on top of that slider.

[image: mat-slider visible behind cdkDrag div]

i reproduced the issue on stackblitz with this template:

```
hello
<mat-slider
  thumbLabel
  tickInterval="1000"
  step="1000"
  min="0"
  max="100000"
  aria-label="units"
></mat-slider
>goodbye
<div
  cdkDrag
  style="background-color: white; 
  border: 1px solid black; padding: 5em;
  position: relative; bottom: 40px;">
  hello
</div>
```

[Stackblitz editor url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ql65gk?file=src/app/app.component.html)

i tried changing `z-index` of that div but results are the same.

any ideas how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with z-index. You just need to set on the right classes and in the right css.

styles.css

```
.mat-slider-thumb {
  z-index: 0 ;
}

.myDiv{
  z-index: 1;
}
```

html

```
...
<div class="myDiv"
  cdkDrag
...
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ygvpqj?file=src/styles.css)

As this can be a bit confusing if you have other sliders, add a class on this one, so you can be more precise in the styling

Comment: thanks it work in my stackblitz. in my own project for some reason i needed to add z-index:0 for div.mat-slider-thumb-container

Answer (score 0):

```
I inspected your Stackblitz url. There I found that value of
```

z-index is set 1 for dark dot.
Below is the css for your reference.
.mat-slider-thumb-container {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
transition: transform 400ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}

```
If you will remove unnecessary 'z-index: 1;' css , then it will work fine.

You need not to add z-index. Hope this answer helped you.
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the info, the .mat-slider-thumb-container is actually part of angular material, that's why i stated in my comment that i needed to set the z-index of that container to 0.